# Tracing the time when a value was updated in a table

Tags: sql, database

Can anybody please, let me know if there is a way to find out the exact time, when a table was updated.I mean when a column was updated. Please, help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

add a trigger, when the inserted (changed) data matches your condition do your notification (insert into log table, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep a LastUpdatedTimeStamp column in my tables where I need that kind of tracking.

If you're asking about tracing a change that has already been made, you might be able to analyze transaction logs.  I don't know how one would go about doing that though.

Comment: this doesn't tell you that the column in question was changed, just something on the row.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is Update Trigger on that table that will call a generic procedure where you can pass parameters like description field name and primary key of updated record as well the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a trigger on update of the relevant column. This will only be triggered if the relevant column actually was changed. Example below is for Oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE
OF my_column
ON my_table
BEGIN
   :new.my_column_updated_at := SYSDATE;
END;
```

`my_column_updated_at` will then track when `my_column` was changed. You may also want to add a trigger on insert to set an initial value of `my_column_updated_at`.

If you need to find out when, for any row in the table, the column was updated, you could issue the following SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(my_column_updated_at) FROM my_table
```